# How to read csv file into pandas, skipping rows until a certain string, then selecting first row after as header and delimiter as |

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Below is an example of a bunch of csv files / datasets I have. They follow the format below.

```
FILE-START
COL=yes
DELIMITER=|
.....
.....
.....

START-DATA
header1 | header2 | header3 | header4 | header5
data1   | data2   | data3   | data4   | data5
......
......
```

I need to skip headers until the string `START-DATA` because each file has a different number of rows before the data starts.

To load this file I can do `pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=50, delimiter = '|')`, but if I want to do a bulk load of all the files this won't work as the data starts at a different row each time.

How can I make this code dynamic so that it starts when the `START-DATA` string appears and takes the following row as a header and uses `|` as a delimiter.

I have tried the following code so far,

```
df = pd.read_csv(downloaded_file, header=None)
df_2 = df.iloc[(df.loc[df[0]=='START-OF-DATA'].index[0]+1):, :].reset_index(drop = True)
```

I start with a dataframe that looks like this,

```
                                             0
0 header1 | header2 | header3 | header4 | header5
1 data1   | data2   | data3   | data4   | data5
```

Where all the data is squeezed into one column. How do I use `|` as the delimiter next?

What's the correct and most efficient way to do this dynamically for each file?

Comment: Did you mean to do `df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)` instead of `df = pd.read_csv(filename)`? That way the column name is `0` rather than `FILE-START` and you should not get a KeyError

Comment: ok that fixed that error, then how do i use `|` as the delimiter after that?

Comment: try something like `df_2[0].str.split('|', expand=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might also work. It reads the df and skips a nr of rows

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skip_blank_lines = False)
start =  df.loc[df.FILE-START == 'START-DATA'].index[0]
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows = start + 2)
```

Comment: df.file_start produces the error that the command does not exist

Comment: Fixed in code example

Comment: now i get an error `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`.

Comment: so there are a lot of blank lines, 8 for this file to be exact, so when I do this method, I am unable to count those lines. do you have a fix for that

Comment: see updated answer. works fine here with a test csv file.

Comment: i modified your code and this works better, 
`df = pd.read_csv(filename, skip_blank_lines = False, header = None)`,
`start =  df.loc[df[0] == 'START-DATA'].index[0]`,
`df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows = start + 1, delimiter='|')`. it works perfectly.

Comment: great, nice work!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to the comments, I will post this answer here until someone can figure out a different or more efficient way.

I have added comments into each line of code.

I could not figure out a way to do it during the csv read and currently have to use 2 dataframes achieve what I need to do.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None) #read all data
df_2 = df.iloc[(df.loc[df[0]=='START-DATA'].index[0]+1):, :].reset_index(drop = True) # make the row after found string as the first row
df_2 = df_2[0].str.split('|', expand=True) # split delimiter using string split.
new_header = df_2.iloc[0] # grab the first row for the header
df_2 = df_2[1:] # take the data less the header row
df_2.columns = new_header #rename columns as the previous first row
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the file with open() search for "START-DATA" and then pass the file-object to pandas.read_csv:

```py
import pandas as pd

with open("FILE-START.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    while line := f.readline():
        if line.strip() == "START-DATA":
            break
    
    df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter="|")
    df.index += 1
```

Comment: doesnt work, even after i change the filename

Comment: @anarchy I added a line to increase the index by one and now I get the exact same result as with the code of your answer.